# Function not defined, even though I defined it

Tags: javascript, html, function

I’m making a game and a function that I defined says that it’s not defined.

I looked and it said that the other person with the same issue had an extra `)` somewhere but I looked and I don’t have that problem.

I don’t have anything extra that is not needed.

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Programing Clicker</title>
  <style>
   h1{
    color:#333;
    font-family:helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:2.5em;
   }
   h2{
    font-size:2em;
    position: relative;
    left:250px;
    display: block;
   }
   h3{
    font-size:1.75em;
    position: relative;
    left: 250px;
    display: block;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <center>
   <h1>Programing Clicker</h1>
   <hr>
  </center>
  <h2>Skill</h2>
  <h3 id="skill_show"></h3>
  <h2>Money</h2>
  <h3 id = "moneyShow"></h3>
  <h2>Language</h2>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p id="timer"></p>
  <button onClick = "scriptMake()">Make a script</button>



  <script>
   var money = 1;
   var skill = 1;
   var language = 1;
   var scriptTime = 100/skill;
   var scriptTime2 = scriptTime;

   function scriptMake(){
    for(var x = 100,x >= 0, x += skill){
     document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = x;
    }
   }
   setInterval(
    function showvars(){
     document.getElementById("skill_show").innerHTML = skill;
     document.getElementById("moneyShow").innerHTML = money;
     
    },1
    ) 
  </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: What function? What's the error exactly?

Comment: when i run the code on my browwser is says the scriptMake function is not defined

Comment: `for(var x = 100,x >= 0, x += skill)` replace your commas with semicolons

Comment: `<DOCTYPE html>` should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`, the `<center>` tag is deprecated — avoid it. Use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately. Use the [browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read the errors: you should see something like “`SyntaxError`: missing `;` after `for`-loop initializer”.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is here

```
for(var x = 100,x >= 0, x += skill){
```

You need semicolons instead of commas like so

```
for(var x = 100;x >= 0; x += skill){
```

Depending on which browser you are using to view the game, look up how to open the console in the browser. It will help you debug these things in a second.